# Select2 - Doesn't show/deletes initial values

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I use `django-filter` for filtering a `Article` queryset. `Article` has a field `locations`:

```
locations = models.ManyToManyField('locations.Location', related_name='articles')
```

I filter `Articles` by field `locations` and as a widget, I use `django-autocomplete-light` widget `Select2Multiple`.

```
class ArticleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    from locations.models import Location
    ...
    locations = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(method='locations_filter',queryset=Location.objects.all(),label='Lokality')
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['locations','title','price_lte','price_gte','price_currency'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # HERE I SPECIFY THE DAL WIDGET
        self.form.fields['locations'].widget = autocomplete.Select2Multiple(url="locations:locations_autocomplete")
```

The filtering works good, autocomplete too:
[image]

When I click on submit, it shows filtered results correctly, URL querystring contains all filtered attributes including for exmaple `locations=45` but it doesn't show the `location` with `id=45` as an initial value for the `locations` field.

[image]

The weird thing is that if I remove the widget, I can see that originally, there is initial value:

[image]

Just `Select2` doesn't show it and the value of locations is `undefinfed`.

I use this same approach on raw `django.forms` and it works correctly. Initials too.

Do you know where can be the problem?